# Identification of kinematics of industrial robots

Tags: calibration, ros-kinetic, robot-calibration, arm-kinematics, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am looking for a way to identify (or calibrate) the kinematic information (Joint angle and robot frame offsets) of my 6-DOF industrial robot. I am aware of the packages [robot_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_calibration) and [pr2_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_calibration).

There still does not seem to be a package which simply optimizes (considering the nominal kinematic information from the manufacturer as a set of start parameters) those parameters and parses them into a new, updated URDF file again.
I thought about a package which takes the endeffector frame (calculated via the direct kinematics) and the measured position of the endeffector as the input and finally optimizes after acquiring a couple of poses the new parameters with e.g the Levenberg-Marquardt optimizer.

Is there any package like that?
Otherwise, I am willing to work on that and would like to contribute.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299042/identification-of-kinematics-of-industrial-robots/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I have not gotten any responses yet, I will simply write a little package for kinematic identification purposes and will post the link to the repository here as soon as I get done.

---

Originally posted by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) with karma: 143 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1